# EasyShell doesn't open terminal correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, eclipse-kepler, ubuntu-14.04

I'm using **EasyShell** plugin with **Eclipse Kepler** on **Ubuntu 14.04**

The plugin works fin when I choose to `explore` a folder or a file but It doesn't work if I choose to `open` the selected file\folder in a terminal. It always opens the terminal to my home folder.

The configured **gnome-terminal** commands runs fine manually, but not through the plugin.
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I fixed it by just removing the quotation marks.

[image: Easy shell configs]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem.  I'm not sure how to fix it via the UI, but you can directly edit the preferences file to fix it:

Edit this file:

```
[WORKSPACE]/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/com.tetrade.eclipse.plugins.easyshell.prefs
```

And add this:

```
targetPreference=gnome-terminal --working-directory\={1}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those, whose problem is not resolved, my solutions is as follows;

1. Go to preferences -> Easyshell
2. Find Open (Gnome) Terminal here and click on it
3. Click on edit and change the command with

   gnome-terminal --working-directory=${easyshell:container_loc}